# Cannot sort posts by tag using acts as taggable on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a method in my `posts_controller`:

```
  def tag
    @posts = Post.all.tagged_with(params[:id]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    render :action => 'index'
  end
```

My routes file :

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get :top
      get :revelance
      get :tag
    end
  end
```

My view file where i output tags: `<%=raw post.tag_list.map {|t| link_to t, tag_posts_path(t), class: "tags" }.join ('  ') %>`

The problem is: When i click on tag i get to url: */posts/tag.Sometag and the page is empty.
Guess i need to change my routes file.. but I don't know what to do

Comment: Do you want to get a page with list of posts by chosen tag? With uri: `/posts/tag/:tag_name` ? (Also you could watch the cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging . There's given many things about tags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need this tag method, you could directly make the job in the `index` action:

```
def index
  @posts = if params[:tag]
    Post.all.tagged_with(params[:tag]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  else
    Post.all.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

Then you can define your route like this:

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
```

And adapt it in your view:

```
<%= raw post.tag_list.map {|t| link_to t, tag_path(t), class: "tags" }.join (' ') %>
```